# Exact match in list in Flutter through RegEx

Tags: regex, flutter, dart

```
String toBeSearched = editingController.text.trim();
toBeSearched.split(' ').forEach((argWord) {
  searchResults.addAll(items
      .where((element) => element.title!.toLowerCase().contains(
          RegExp(element.title!)
              .hasMatch(argWord)
              .toString())) 
      .toList());
});
```

This is failing to return all occurances of the "argWord" in the "title" field of the element.
Please guide

Answer (score 0):

See here is there's no requirement of using `RegExp`.

This can be done only by using string operation like below,
You just populate the `searchResult` list with `elements` having `argWord` in their `title`.

```
String toBeSearched = editingController.text.trim();
toBeSearched.split(' ').forEach((argWord) {
  searchResults.addAll(items
      .where((element) =>
          element.title!.toLowerCase().contains(argWord.toLowerCase()))
      .toList());
});
```